# Rayleigh quotients being the diagonal entry of a matrix after orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

In "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethan and Bau, there is the following question:

Let A $\in \mathbb{C}^{m\times m}$, not necessarily Hermitian, and $z$ is a number. Show that $z$ is a Rayleigh quotient of $A$ if and only if it is a diagonal entry of $Q^*AQ$ for some unitary matrix $Q$.

I don't really know where to start, but I'm thinking it has something to do with eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $A$. I know that $R[A,x] \in [\lambda_{\min},\lambda_{\max}]$ as a Rayleigh quotient is a weighted average of the eigenvalues of $A$. I think its the unitary matrices that are throwing me off here. I know that the Rayleigh quotient for a matrix $A$ and vector $x$ is defined as:

$$R(x) = \cfrac{x^*Ax}{x^*x}$$

Thanks for any help/suggestions.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider a matrix $Q$ whose first row is $z^* = v_1^*$, so that $Q^*$ can be written as the columns
$$
Q^* = [v_1\quad v_2\quad\cdots\quad v_n]
$$
Consider the block-matrix product $QAQ^*$, and show that that the $i$th diagonal entry is $q_i^*Aq_i$.